# How to implement Circular Permutation (left and right shift) of CSR_Matrix in Scipy Python Sparse Matrices?

Tags: python, scipy, permutation, sparse-matrix

I am using Scipy sparse matrix `csr_matrix` to be used as context vectors in word-context vectors. My `csr_matrix` is a `(1, 300)` shape so it is a 1-dimensional vector.

I need to use permutation (circular right shift or circular left shift) on the sparse vector (for showing left context and right context).

example:
i have `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and i want to create right and left permutations as follow:

right permutation: `[4, 1, 2, 3]`
left permutation:  `[2, 3, 4, 1]`

In csr matrices i can't access to column indices so i can not just change the column indices.

Is there any efficient high performance solution for row permutations in `csr_matrix` or am i missing something?

runnable code:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
rows = [0, 0, 0]
columns = [100, 47, 150]
data = [-1, +1, -1]
contextMatrix = csr_matrix( (data,(rows, columns)), shape=(1, 300) )
```

it means that i have a 300-column vector whose columns 100, 47, 150 all from row 0 are non-zero valued and their value is in data list respectively.

now what i want is a permutation which means i want the columns array be changed into
[101, 48, 151] for right permutation and [99, 46, 149] for left permutation.

It should be noted that permutations are circular which means if column 299 has non-zero data, using a right permutation the data will be moved to column 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access and alter the `data` and `indices` attributes of your CSR matrix, which are stored as NumPy arrays.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

So using your code and following the suggestion in the comments you could do this:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
rows = [0, 0, 0]
columns = [100, 47, 150]
data = [-1, +1, -1]
m = csr_matrix( (data,(rows, columns)), shape=(1, 300) )

indices = m.indices

# right permutation
m.indices = (indices + 1) % m.shape[1]

# left permutation
m.indices = (indices - 1) % m.shape[1]
```

Comment: You can just say: `the_matrix.indices = (the_matrix.indices+1)%the_matrix.shape[1]` I guess

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I tested it and it works great.